# Controlling popup or new window behaviour in dual monitor displays

Tags: browser, window, email-client, multiple-monitors

When I have the web browser open on the secondary monitor on a dual monitor display that is configured as two separate screens I notice that if you click on a website to share an article by email then the popup window of the email client will show up on the primary display screen (where I am running the application).

Is there a way to control the popup so that it appears on the same screen that the browser application is running because sometimes it gets hidden behind other applications on the primary display so you think that the share link is not working?

Answer (score 2):

I have qty 4 24" monitors running on a Dell 690 with 2 FX Quadro 4500 video cards. Each one drives 2 monitors, which are configured as one long monitor of 8K x 2K pixels. A few things I have noticed that seem etched in concrete.
1. If the parent of the new window is your browser, it usually but not always pops up over or next to the browser. Since you can drag it anywhere you like I would not fuss over where it pops up at. I have had just clicked-on programs pop up on my 3rd or 4th monitor, so I had to drag it over to where I wanted it.
2. Monitor 1, the 'home' monitor, always has the desktop icons and any add-on gadgets confined to its screen. Its code may push new windows to a monitor with a less crowded screen, or accept a new pop-up screen if that window is low on the z-index. I.E., it is not claiming rights to be on top off other windows.
3. Best way that I avoid hidden windows with so many monitors and CAD programs running is to make sure each window is set NOT to fill the screen. It if is not in use at that moment I shrink it down to the system tray.
4. Notepad and LabView seem to be the only programs so far that I can stretch across 2 or 4 screens with no corruption in the program. Excel may crash if you do this and MSword tends to get its lines out of sync. To some degree the programs have to be aware of multiple monitors, and very few are.
5. Each monitor has its own video buffer ram (ddram). This is the unseen barrier that programs need to be aware of when it is stretched out across multiple screens or creates a child window. If these extra large pixels spaces are not accounted for by the program-not the OS, then corruption or loss of the new window are very possible. The browser may not even be aware of where its child window popped up at.
6. PC's can only be intuitive up to a certain point. With many screens and apps running the user needs to manage it all.

Comment: What kind of program is LabView (since there might be a few with the same name)?

Comment: @Michael Lai. LabView is created by National Instruments, and they own the copyrights to it and its code. Look them up on the internet or Google them. Look up their 'LabView' program. It would take much writing for me to explain what it is and all that it can do.

Comment: Also, how does the browser or desktop application (or graphics display driver) decide where the window is opened in multi-display configurations?

Comment: @Maichael Lai. Honestly it seems random at times,  but when I open a child window in my browser using JS it always appears at position x=0, y=0. But Email is it's own program and may not dictate to the OS where to open the window or if it is to be in front of other windows. Best as I can tell it is up to the program as to how and where a new window opens. If it is not coded into the program,  the OS will use default values.

Comment: @Michael Lai. I have done a bit of experimenting. My email and some program comments pop-up in the middle of the 1st screen, but behind any active window. My antivirus and firewall also put messages in the center of the 1st screen, but in front of any active window. These positioning and visibility issues are up to the programs and what instructions they give to the OS.

Comment: Can you update your answer with some of the details because I would like to give it a tick. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106524/discussion-between-sparky256-and-michael-lai).